# Coinduction in a presheaf topos?

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory

Fix a presheaf topos $\mathcal{E}\triangleq \mathbf{Set}^{\mathcal{C}^\mathsf{op}}$. Then, for any object/presheaf $X:\mathcal{E}$, I can define the presheaf of relations on $X$ as $\wp(X)\triangleq\Omega^{X}$, where the exponential is defined in the usual way for a presheaf category.

Now, let's say that I have got a natural transformation $\phi:\wp(X)\to\wp(X)$ such that $\phi$ is monotonic. Is there some way I can take the greatest fixed point of $\phi$ to get something like $\nu(\phi) : \mathbb{1}\to\wp(X)$?

[I'm also not certain if I've formulated the above question properly, or if there is perhaps something better that I ought to be doing. In addition to answers, I'm open to constructive criticism of the question, since there's no better way to learn!]

Comment: No, the negation operator on $\Omega$ induces a natural transformation on $\wp(X)$ that has no fixed point. You might want to restrict to monotonic transformations on $\wp(X)$. The Knaster-Tarski theorem is constructive.

Comment: Hi Todd, thanks very much for your remark! I take it to mean that if $\phi$ is monotone, then I can get its greatest fixed point.

It makes sense to me, since I would expect to be able to do all the usual constructions in a topos, but I just wasn't sure. Having searched about a bit, it looks like Lemma 4.1.10 of Sketches vol 2 is precisely what I was looking for. Thanks again!